# How to make an ongoing list in an Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing a macro where I'm just copy/pasting all of the data in a daily sheet to a monthly sheet. However, the data is always uploaded to the same cells.

My question is how can I make it so that everytime I activate the macro, it uploads at the end of the previous days instead of a fixed position? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("sheet.xlsx").Activate
Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
```

****Range("A1224").Select****

Comment: You might consider reading [how to find the last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba). Also [paste on next empty row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662029/vba-paste-on-next-empty-row).

Comment: Side note: You will also want to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Answer (score 1):

### Append Table Data Using `CurrentRegion`

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**The Code**

```vb
Sub AppendTableData()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Append Table Data"
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_FIRST_DATA_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Monthly"
    Const DST_FIRST_DATA_CELL As String = "A2"
    
    ' Use an array of names of the sheets that you don't want to be written to.
    Dim Exclusions(): Exclusions = Array("Monthly", "Dummy") ' add more

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Dim sName As String: sName = sws.Name
    
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(sName, Exclusions, 0)) Then
        MsgBox "The sheet """ & sName & """ is selected." & vbLf _
            & "Please select one of the daily sheets.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_DATA_CELL)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    
    With sCell.CurrentRegion
        Set srg = sCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - sCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - sCell.Column)
    End With
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_DATA_CELL)
    
    Dim drrg As Range, IsDataRangeEmpty As Boolean
    
    With dCell.CurrentRegion
        Set drrg = dCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - dCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - dCell.Column)
        If drrg.Rows.Count = 1 Then ' the destination data range has one row
            If Application.CountA(drrg) = 0 Then ' the dest. data range is empty
                IsDataRangeEmpty = True
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsDataRangeEmpty Then
            Set dCell = drrg.Cells(1).Offset(drrg.Rows.Count)
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Copy.
    
    srg.Copy dCell

    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "The daily data from sheet """ & sName & """ has been copied " _
        & "to sheet """ & DST_SHEET & """!", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    
'    Debug.Print String(43, "-")
'    Debug.Print "Sheet", "Name", "Range Reference"
'    Debug.Print String(43, "-")
'    Debug.Print "Source", sws.Name, srg.Address
'    Debug.Print "Destination", dws.Name, dCell.Address
    
End Sub
```

**MsgBox**

[image]

**Result in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)**

```
-------------------------------------------
Sheet         Name          Range Reference
-------------------------------------------
Source        2023-08-25    $A$2:$C$3
Destination   Monthly       $A$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have two "sheets", which I assume are in the same workbook. To ensure you are copying data from/to the correct sheets, I suggest you specify the worksheet with the `Range` function. To append the data to a new row, use `Range.End(xlDown).Offset(1)`. I also think it'd be best to resize the destination range to have the same number of rows and columns as the source range. Finally, the `Range.Copy` method can take a `Destination` parameter so that copying and pasting all happens in one operation.

```vb
Dim dailySheet As Worksheet, monthlySheet As Worksheet
Dim startCell as Range, source as Range, destination as Range
Dim nextRow As Range

Set dailySheet = Worksheets("daily_sheet_name")
Set monthlySheet = Worksheet("monthly_sheet_name")

Set startCell = dailySheet.Range("A2")
Set source = Range(startCell, startCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

Set nextRow = monthlySheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
Set destination = nextRow.Resize(RowSize:=source.Rows.Count, ColumnSize:=source.Columns.Count)

source.Copy Destination:=destination
```